# Is there a point in collecting all the flags in Assassin's Creed?

Tags: assassins-creed

There are many collectable flags throughout the game of Assassin's Creed and every time one is collected, you get a progress indicator (e.g., 33 of 100).  Is there any reason to collect these, other than bragging rights?  I recall getting all available flags in one particular town and never saw any special reward or secret revealed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The point is only to get the achievement. You don't unlock anything by collecting them.

There are 4 achievements associated with flags:

1. [Keeper of the lions passant](http://www.trueachievements.com/a14521/keeper-of-the-lions-passant-achievement.htm) - Find all of Richard's flags in the Kingdom
2. [Keeper of the creed](http://www.trueachievements.com/a11298/keeper-of-the-creed-achievement.htm) - Find all flags in Masyaf
3. [Keeper of the four gospels](http://www.trueachievements.com/a15098/keeper-of-the-four-gospels-achievement.htm) - Find all flags in Jerusalem
4. [Keeper of the crescent](http://www.trueachievements.com/a15100/keeper-of-the-crescent-achievement.htm) - Find all flags in Damascus

Comment: should be noted that AC1 only had achievements on the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: That's correct Kip ... there is no point in collecting all flags neither killing all Templars in the PS3 version of the game since no trophies will be awarded.

Comment: @Kip The PC version also has achievements, but they are localized to your own system and aren't displayed to the public.

Comment: The point of achievements is that it is easier to show others what you have done. You can still brag that you've collected everything.

Answer (score 6):

The only usage for these flags is to have a save point in-game in case you die.