# Is there any reward for completing all the memories and collecting all the flags?

Tags: assassins-creed

Do you get anything after collecting all the different flags and completing all the memories so everything is full? I don't want to try and collect everything in every memory if I don't get anything in the end.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a possible duplicate of [THIS](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/is-there-a-point-in-collecting-all-the-flags-in-assassins-creed) question.

To answer your question, collecting the flags does not net you anything special other than the achievements.

Comment: it isn't completely a duplicate since it also mentions the mission completion...

Comment: If you're going to claim that a question is a duplicate of another, don't post an _answer_ stating that. Leave a comment, flag/close it as a duplicate, you have the necessary reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Completing all missions available early in the will net you more health blocks faster, but there's an upper limit to the health blocks so eventually completing more missions than required has no added effect.

Collecting all flags nets you an achievement on the Xbox 360 version of the game.